# Parallelizing FTP requests (MLSD) with ftplib

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

I am trying to crawl an FTP server in parallel to find out the directory structure, using Python's `ftplib`. My algorithm as such just sends the MLSD command, parses all the subdirectories from the MLSD response, and recurses for every subdirectory. To parallelize it I am pushing the MLSD commands on a queue and have threads that work the queue. Everything works fine with one thread working on the queue, but as soon as I put more than one thread to work on the queue I get lots of errors including

```
ftplib.error_reply: 200 Type set to A
ftplib.error_reply: 226 Sucessfully transferred ""
ftplib.error_reply: 150 Opening data channel for directory listing of "/Artikeldaten deutsch/UPD200709"
ftplib.error_perm: 503 Bad sequence of commands.
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

Is there a good solution for this problem?

Comment: If you have multiple threads talking to the same server connection, no wonder it gets confused. The good solution is to not do that.

Comment: The problem is that I am working with a server that contains about 80'000 directories. It takes an entire day to get the structure without multithreading.

Comment: You need to have one FTP session per parallel task. Probably you can use threading but you obviously cannot have all the clients talking in the same control channel at the same time. If this is a remote server, probably letting it take time is better than flooding them with your clients just because you are curious.

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice, I think this is the problem. However you are very much allowed to keep your opinions to yourself.